# Delete object element only inside the function

Tags: javascript, json, object

**The core problem:** 
There is a given object, There is a given element of object. I want to check is there any other element in the object expect this given element. For example there is an object:

```
object = {
  example1: "text1",
  example2: "text2"
}
```

How can I check is there any other element expect `example1`?

**My solution:**
I have a function which get an object as parameter. The objects are constants.

```
function checkObjectOfElements(object, element)
{
    var filters = object;
    delete filters[element];
    if (filters["test1"] != undefined ||
        filters["test2"] != undefined ||
        filters["test3"] != undefined ||
        filters["test4"] != undefined) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The first parameter the object the second the elemet what I want to delete.

**The problem:**
Basically I don't want to delete this element, just checking is there any other element expect these in the object, but if I call the delete for the element its not only delete inside the function, but delete globally. I think it is getting as pointer, but I didn't found any other solution for getting the parameter not as a pointer.

Comment: Make a copy/clone of the object, manipulate it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple. Check there exists some key which name is not `element`

```
function checkObjectOfElements(obj, element) {
   return Object.keys(obj).some(name => name !== element)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the size of the object like this:

```
Object.keys(object).length
```

And you can write a condition:

```
element in object
```

With this infos, you can decide wether your object contains only this specified element or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correct - you just need to know you have only concrete single property in your object?

Does this help?

```js
function checkPropSingle(obj, prop) {
  for(var key in obj) {
    if(key !== prop) {
      return false;
    }
  }
    
  return true;
}

var obj1 = {a:1, b:2, c:3},
  obj2 = {a:1, b:2},
  obj3 = {a:1};

console.log(checkPropSingle(obj1, 'a'));
console.log(checkPropSingle(obj2, 'a'));
console.log(checkPropSingle(obj3, 'a'));
```